# How to Sum sub nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have incoming xml structure to XSLT is like below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TimeAccount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <userId>123</userId>
        <timeAccountDetails>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>190</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <employeeTime>e885f88ccaa647abb00a8f84bcf5aa32</employeeTime>
                <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-04-19T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <employeeTime>e885f88ccaa647abb00a8f84bcf5aa32</employeeTime>
                <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-04-20T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>120</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <employeeTime>e885f88ccaa647abb00a8f84bcf5aa32</employeeTime>
                <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-04-21T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
        </timeAccountDetails>
    </TimeAccount>
        <TimeAccount>
        <userId>456</userId>
        <timeAccountDetails>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>190</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <employeeTime>e885f88ccaa647abb00a8f84bcf5aa32</employeeTime>
                <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-04-19T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-06-01T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>100</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
            <TimeAccountDetail>
                <employeeTime>e885f88ccaa647abb00a8f84bcf5aa32</employeeTime>
                <bookingType>EMPLOYEE_TIME</bookingType>
                <bookingUnit>HOURS</bookingUnit>
                <bookingDate>2021-04-21T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
                <bookingAmount>-8</bookingAmount>
            </TimeAccountDetail>
        </timeAccountDetails>
    </TimeAccount>
</TimeAccount>
```

I want output as below by adding bookingAmount for each userId

```
<TimeAccount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
        <bookingAmount>310</bookingAmount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <TimeAccount>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
        <bookingAmount>290</bookingAmount>
    <TimeAccount>
</TimeAccount>
```

I wrote my xslt as below, using for-each and a if condition and then using SUM function.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <TimeAccount>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </TimeAccount>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TimeAccount/TimeAccount">
        <TimeAccount>
          <ID><xsl:value-of select="userId"/></ID>         
          <bookingAmount>
            <xsl:for-each select="timeAccountDetails/TimeAccountDetail">
                <xsl:if test="bookingType != 'EMPLOYEE_TIME'">
                   <xsl:value-of select="sum(bookingAmount)"/> 
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </TimeAccount>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is not adding the bookingAmounts nodes, it is printing the nodes side by side.

```
<TimeAccount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <bookingAmount>190 120</bookingAmount>
    <TimeAccount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <bookingAmount>190 100</bookingAmount>
    <TimeAccount>
<TimeAccount>
```

What am I doing wrong?  I tried keeping / before booking amount like sum(/bookingAmount) which prints null and if I put // then it prints total of all user's bookingAmounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XSLT code to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/TimeAccount">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TimeAccount" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="TimeAccount">
      <xsl:copy>
        <ID><xsl:value-of select="userId"/></ID> 
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>        
        <bookingAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(timeAccountDetails/TimeAccountDetail[bookingType != 'EMPLOYEE_TIME']/bookingAmount)"/></bookingAmount>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TimeAccount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
        <bookingAmount>310</bookingAmount>
    </TimeAccount>
    <TimeAccount>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
        <bookingAmount>290</bookingAmount>
    </TimeAccount>
</TimeAccount>
```

I fixed the `<bookingType>` to "MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT", because you only want these values (all that are not `EMPLOYEE_TIME`).

BTW you only need XSLT-1.0 for this task. XSLT-3.0 capability is just a bonus.

Comment: That works like a magic, when compared to my code did <xsl:copy> made all the difference or looping through nodes?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This xslt give the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="userId">
    <ID>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </ID>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="timeAccountDetails">
    <bookingType>MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT</bookingType>
    <bookingAmount>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(TimeAccountDetail[bookingType='MANUAL_ADJUSTMENT']/bookingAmount)"/>
    </bookingAmount>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While you are using xslt 3.0 you can use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Which is the same as:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And will just copy anything that you don't have a template-match for.